# move item with specific element drag and drop jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

hello I have  list on the left , when I drag element it must be moved to element matches
in this code :
-I tried to create each element a data-id and if both id are equal it slips into the corresponding element
-it works if I move StoreID but in ItemLookupCode not worked

```js
$(function() {
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    update: function(e, ui) {
      var s=ui.item.attr("data-id");

var s1=$("#sortable2 li").attr("data-id");

      if (s ==s1) {
    
 
     
      }
      if (s!=s1){
      alert("no")
        ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
      }
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.connectedSortable {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 {
  background: #fff;
}

#sortable2 {
  background: #999;
}

.connectedSortable li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-id="2" class="ui-state-default acceptable">StoreID</li>
  <li data-id="3" class="ui-state-default">ItemLookupCode</li>
  <li data-id="4" class="ui-state-default">ExtendedCost</li>
  <li data-id="5" class="ui-state-default">Quantity</li>
  <li data-id="6" class="ui-state-default">Price</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-id="2"></li>
    <li data-id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many things will need to be fixed in your code to ir work as expected, but to start `$("#sortable2 li").attr("data-id");` is selecting all `li` inside the `#sortable2`, but `attr` is getting the `data-id` of just the first element that it found (that's why `"StoreID"` works and others don't), think about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code. First when you move sortable1 item to sortable2, the attribute will be copied to sortable2, so change attribute name for sortable2 to prevent mixing up. Then you should check all the items in sortable2.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    update: function(e, ui) {
      if (!ui.sender) return
      var s = ui.item.attr("data-id");
      var matches = $("#sortable2 li[data-target=" + s + "]").length
      if (matches === 0) {
        ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
      }
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.connectedSortable {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: move;
}

#sortable1 {
  background: #fff;
}

#sortable2 {
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-id="2" class="ui-state-default acceptable">StoreID</li>
  <li data-id="3" class="ui-state-default">ItemLookupCode</li>
  <li data-id="4" class="ui-state-default">ExtendedCost</li>
  <li data-id="5" class="ui-state-default">Quantity</li>
  <li data-id="6" class="ui-state-default">Price</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-target="2"></li>
  <li data-target="3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Forget to add the jquery library. Try again.

Comment: sorry i edit your code but it'not workes for example if I slip the date it must match the black rectangle https://jsfiddle.net/jaafar/9xvj67bd/42/

Comment: I actually don't know what you want. But I guess you want to put list item into matched list. Here is my code [https://jsfiddle.net/Yajie/gvzhtjnr/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/Yajie/gvzhtjnr/8/).If it is not what you want,  Perhaps it can inspire you.

Comment: two question if you like it's possible to keep the fields after drag and become disable

Comment: Try the code [https://jsfiddle.net/Yajie/jqmL98ot/33/](https://jsfiddle.net/Yajie/jqmL98ot/33/). you should be familiar with API of jQuery and Sortable Widget to handle all the needs.

Comment: just last question it is possible to add a hover to the target area  
and if I slide the element to this position I do not slide it agai

Comment: of course. if you read the api, you will find the event `over` and `out`. Here is my code. [https://jsfiddle.net/Yajie/jqmL98ot/75/](https://jsfiddle.net/Yajie/jqmL98ot/75/)

Comment: yes it works but for example if I slip the date the hover must be in the date zone

Comment: another thing how blocks the slip after drag

Comment: can help please